# Sort by label_from_instance with ModelMultipleChoiceField in Django 1.8

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a form with a `ModelMultipleChoiceField` that has been overridden to specify a `label_from_instance`. What's the best way to sort the choices by the label?

```
class MultipleAuthorChoiceField(forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        label = author_display(obj)
        return super(MultipleAuthorChoiceField, self).label_from_instance(label)
```

I understand that I can `order_by` the queryset that I pass in. While that works to sort the queryset, it's not going to be sorted by the `label_from_instance`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with:

```
from operator import itemgetter

class MultipleAuthorChoiceField(forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        label = author_display(obj)
        return super(MultipleAuthorChoiceField, self).label_from_instance(label)

    def _get_choices(self):
        choices = super(MultipleAuthorChoiceField, self)._get_choices()
        for choice in sorted(choices, key=itemgetter(1)):
            yield choice
    choices = property(_get_choices, forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField._set_choices)
```